# Задание фона

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, такой вопрос: есть код первой страницы, как сделать фон? Хотя бы просто цвет...

```
<?php
if ($stranica == "ГЛАВНАЯ") {
    echo "<p>ГЛАВНАЯ</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p><a href='index2.php'>Table1</a></p>";
    echo "<p><a href='index3.php'>Table2</a></p>";
    echo "<p><a href='index4.php'>Table3</a></p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: фон чего? страницы(body)?

Comment: да, страницы

Comment: скриптом:
<?php
    
if ($stranica == "ГЛАВНАЯ")
    
{   echo "<script>document.body.style.background='red';</script>";
    
echo "<p>ГЛАВНАЯ</p>";
    
}    
else
    
{.......  }
    
?>

Comment: @wicS - начните с основ html, css, а не с php

PS: нормальные люди не выводят html в `echo`

PPS: `stranica` вы что 1С-шник? =)

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт? Bgcolor? Люди, зачем вы даёте вредные советы?

Можно сделать так:

```
echo "<style>body { bacgkround: #ebaeba; }</style>";
```

(выводим в тело страницы тег style, в котором описываем внешний вид через css-правила)

Но лучше так:

```
include('layouts/index.php');
```

(включаем в вывод содержимое скрипта layouts/index.php, в котором хранить только HTML c подстановками необходимых переменных и т.д. это сделаем для того, чтобы уменьшить сложность нашего скрипта, так как в будущем в каше из CSS, HTML, PHP даже опытному программисту будет сложно разобраться)

И в файле layouts/index.php:

```
<doctype !html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8" />
    <link href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Главная</title>
</head>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Главная</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

(в файле только разметка, и, возможно, циклы и условия для вывода значений переменных, полученных в главном скрипте. пока у нас вывода переменных нет, но это делается легко: `<p><?=$var;?></p>`. `<?=$var;?>` — это короткая запись `<?php echo $var; ?>`)

А в файле css/main.css:

```
body {
    background: #F1337F;
}
```

(тут хранится CSS для определения внешнего вида элементов страницы)

Answer (score -1):

Тривиально:

```
echo "<body bgcolor='$bgcolor' color='$color'>";
echo "пиши сюда";
echo "</body>";
```

Можно поумничать и задать джава-скриптом, который пораждается рнр и меняет у боди бекграунд-колор. Можно еще поумничать и задавать сиэсэску динамически через рнр переменную. Можно, наконец, разработать движок в котором динамически подключать стили страницы и настраивать страницу по желанию пользователя.